# Dependencies preventing Node app build in Heroku

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, node-modules

I have an app that I'm trying to push an update to heroku, but the build keeps failing. The error I get from the heroku log is:

```
Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules
   npm ERR! Cannot read property '@babel/polyfill' of undefined
   
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I tried replacing babel with a different package, but it gives me the exact same error but for a different dependency (google-auth), so I tried swapping the order of the dependencies in my package.json, and the error just 'picks whatever is top of the list', so I'm pretty sure it's a broad problem rather than an individual dependency.

I contacted heroku and they recommended I try purging the cache, deleting the package.json lock file and the node modules folder, and running npm install. I tried that, problem is the same.

The app works in my local environment, the only thing I can think that I have done that would have had an affect since the last successful push to heroku, was a script I have using parcel-bundler to build a javascript bundle file and a node-sass script to watch my styles. These stopped working, so I installed nvm and ran 'nvm use 12', which got the scripts working again.

I specify node version and npm version in my package json, so I'm not sure why this would be an issue on heroku.